# Load JWT signature key from a dynamic base

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I deployed an Authorization Server using `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` and the users and clients are configured from the implementation of the `UserDetailsService` and `ClientDetailsService` services that gather the required information in the database.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2JwtAuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private  UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        private AppClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

        @Override
        public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {          
            clients.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService);
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
            final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
            defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            return defaultTokenServices;
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            final TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
            tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));

            endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
            .reuseRefreshTokens(false)
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
        }

        @Bean
        public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
            final JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
            converter.setSigningKey("123");

            return converter;
        }

        @Bean
        public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
            return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
        }

        @Bean
        public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
}
```

The Authorization Server is working properly, but I would like the signature key set in the `accessTokenConverter ()` method to be loaded dynamically, when I receive the request for a new Token, I would access the database and modify the Signing Key at this point and return the JWT Token with this new modified signature, it is currently only being configured the moment the application is started.

Comment: Can you please post the answer, if you got it already. I am have also same requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an @Autowired JwtAccessTokenConverter property and modify its key at any point

```
@Autowired
public JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter;

public void setSigningKey(String key) {
    tokenConverter.setSigningKey(key);
}
```